# Generalized elliptic curves over cusps and orbits of $\mathbb{Q}\cup\infty$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry

In the post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51147/what-objects-do-the-cusps-of-modular-curve-classify, it says that the fibers over the cusps of a modular curve are n-gons. Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_curve) says that the cusps are the orbits of $\mathbb{Q}\cup\infty$ under the action of the congruence subgroup. As a naive question, if we are working over $\mathbb{C}$, is it possible to tell what lies over a cusp by considering the orbit?